# Sorting issues, and warnings using array_multisort() Array sizes are inconsistent

Tags: php, sorting, array-multisort

As you can see the 2d array is as following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Bregu i Diellit [2] => 7 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Tasligje [2] => 4 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Bregu i Diellit [2] => 4 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Bregu i Diellit [2] => 3 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Bregu i Diellit [2] => 9 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Lakrishte [2] => 4 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Lakrishte [2] => 6 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Lakrishte [2] => 1 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Ulpiana [2] => 3 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Ulpiana [2] => 6 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Ulpiana [2] => 5 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Ulpiana [2] => 8 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Ulpiana [2] => 4 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Ulpiana [2] => 8 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Velania [2] => 2 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Velania [2] => 5 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Velania [2] => 1 ) 
    [17] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Dragodan [2] => 9 ) 
    [18] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Dragodan [2] => 7 ) 
    [19] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Dragodan [2] => 10 ) 
    [20] => Array ( [0] => Prishtina [1] => Velania [2] => 11 ) 
    [21] => Array ( [0] => Mitrovica [1] => Qender [2] => 5 ) 
    [22] => Array ( [0] => Mitrovica [1] => Qender [2] => 3 ) 
    [23] => Array ( [0] => Mitrovica [1] => Tavnik [2] => 6 ) 
    [24] => Array ( [0] => Mitrovica [1] => Tavnik [2] => 9 ) 
    [25] => Array ( [0] => Mitrovica [1] => Bair [2] => 10 ) 
    [26] => Array ( [0] => Mitrovica [1] => Bair [2] => 12 ) 
    [27] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

I am trying to sort by the 3rd column with the following code:

```
foreach ($final_array as $roww){
    $sort_column[]= $roww[2];   // 2 = your example
    array_multisort($sort_column, $final_array);
}
```

However when im printing:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($final_array); $row++)
{
    foreach($final_array[$row] as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
 }
```

WHen i am printing, it sorts and it prints the array as sorted by the 3rd column, however it is bringing me these warnings

```
Warning: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: Array sizes are inconsistent in   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 35
 Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 34
```

I am not sure why is this happening, it doesnt make sense to me, everything is working however i need these warnings out!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning as there is an undefined reference to your array at index `27`. The warning is saying that you are trying to use that value but it doesn't exist.

Take another look at your array

Comment: the array is sorted and is printed as required! It could be maybe because the array $sort_column is not 2D array!

Answer (score 0):

array_multisort() if used to sort many arrays at once echoes warning, if all of the arrays chosen to perform multisort on are different in a matter of size:

```
$arr = array(
    'UK' => array(
        'John' => 'Toyota',
        'Alice' => 'Opel',
        'Evan' => 'Fiat',
        'Gregory' => 'Mitsubishi'
    ),
    'Germany' => array(
        'Bruno' => 'Opel',
        'Andreas' => 'Mercedes',
        'Klaus' => 'Porsche',
    )
);
```

See? Number of elements in both arrays differ. So, array_multisort will try to sort these arrays in the same way, even if options are different:

```
array_multisort(
    $arr['Germany'], SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL,
    $arr['UK'], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC
    );
```

This will print a warning like:
Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent in (...)

Answer (score 0):

Another condition that will throw an "array sizes are inconsistent" occurs when the same key name or names are used in two unrelated multi-dimensional arrays. You can still use the same key names if you clear the key name prior to setting columns in the second multi-dimensional array. If doing this is discouraged, I'd be interested in knowing why.